# videojs - how to show thumbnails as the progress-slider is moved

Tags: html, video.js

On YouTube's player, when you hover on progress-bar and traverse your mouse along, you see a series of thumbnails, as well as time-values.  This is great, when you're tying to find a scene that you know of visually, and want its time-value.

Whereas, on videojs player, you see only time-values.

(On X-Finity (Comcast, their fast-forward similarly shows rapid series of thumbnails.  But, googling seems to reveal that Videojs doesn't have fast-forward.  And, I think I'd prefer YouTube's feature over a fast-forward.)

So, bottom-line question is:  How to make Videojs player behave like YouTube's?

(I'm thinking this would be difficult to implement for the end-user, in javascript.  Detecting that the slider is being moved is no doubt straight-forward, but code to display thumbnails would be the part that I have NO IDEA
how to accomplish.)

Anyone know how to program this?

Answer (score 2):

BrightCove developed a 'thumbnails' plugin that implements this.
See their example coding here:
    https://support.brightcove.com/display-thumbnail-previews-plugin#Example

There is more specific discussion on the subject in this forum here:
    [How to generate video preview thumbnails for use in VideoJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900022)

My first cut at implementing the notion is here:
    https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/