# videojs-thumbnails plugin shows thumbnails at incorrect time

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to use "videojs-thumbnails" plugin from https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-thumbnails and noticed that thumbnail's time, specified in the plugin configuration is not matching the timestamp in the seek bar. Coming across different comments regarding this issue I found suggestion at https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-thumbnails/issues/43 to replace line

```
mouseTime = Math.floor((left - progressControl.el().offsetLeft) / progressControl.width() * duration);
```

to

```
mouseTime = Math.floor((left) / progressControl.width() * duration);
```

By removing

```
- progressControl.el().offsetLeft
```

However, that produces still not exact time match.
Finally I came with redefined value for the

```
var left
```

Getting it from the current value of

```
.vjs-mouse-display
```

So, my final codes are:

```
left=parseInt((document.querySelector('.vjs-mouse-display').style.left),10);
mouseTime = Math.floor((left) / progressControl.width() * duration);
```

Now everything works correctly.
Greatly appreciate for comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT an answer to your specific question / issue, but rather, an alternative implentation approach.

I, too, wanted thumbnails for my video(s), so I proto-typed a page
that used videoJS's plugin.  I don't recall all the details of the
issues that I ran into trying to use that plugin, but I finally decided
to abandon the plugin, and design an alternative, which has its own
separate 'slider' just above the viewer. [ One 'drags' my slider,
(rather than hover along it, as you do on YouTube's videos), so that it
can work straight-forwardly on touch-screens...i.e. on Android, etc. ]

And, rather than try to extract images from the video in real-time,
(See:  [How to generate video preview thumbnails for use in VideoJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900022/how-to-generate-video-preview-thumbnails-for-use-in-videojs) ), I chose to prepare the images, ahead of time, using 'ffmpeg' and the cmd-line interface to 'ImageMagick'.
Details of that part are here:
http://weasel.firmfriends.us/GeeksHomePages/subj-video-and-audio.html#implementing-video-thumbnails

My 'proof-of-concept' webpage based on that approach is here:
    https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: The reason of my post, is to share my solution of the issue with this plugin. Due to the public availability of this open source software I believe it is still attractive for the web developers. Unfortunately your 'proof-of-concept' webpage doesn't shows thumbnails and doesn't allow to drag the thumbnails slider in Firefox (it does in Chrome). As far as I know there is no such plugin for VideoJS, that allows you to extract images from the video in real-time. All of them use the predefined series of images as list in the HTML body or in the external VTT file. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yes, it DOES show thumbnails. (I'm guessing that you might have tried it during the time yesterday or the day before, when I was tweaking the URL of the thumbnail files.)  Try it again. As to the problem you saw in Firefox, my bug there clearly got fixed AFTER I ported it to my 'production' webpage, which DOES work fine in Firefox.  That page is here: https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Soft-VTT-Cloud/  And, yes, you're correct about there NOT being a thumbnail-plugin for VideoJS directly. Your base post called the Brightcove plugin a "VideoJS" plugin, as I did. Lastly, there's a slider-bug in Edge.

Comment: A few months ago, I upgraded my implementation, so that it NO LONGER has the external separate 'slider' to view thru the thumbnails. It now visually resembles YouTube's implementation.  See: https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/