# How to make thumb pictures in js video player like in youtube?

Tags: video, video.js, video-player, video-thumbnails

I found no one library in npm which is provides us video-seek-slider with thumb picture view. Accordingly I don't understand, what should I do to make it:

1. How to make thumbs pictures available on frontend side?
2. where to find any npm client side progress which is already implements showing of a thumb `onMouseOver` event?

[image]

Could any one to support me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled with this exact issue, about a year ago.  Based on the
thread here: [How to generate video preview thumbnails for use in VideoJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900022/)
I finally concluded to go with offline generation of thumbnails, as it's
much easier than trying to extract them on-the-fly.

I did a technical discussion/explanation of that struggle here:
    http://weasel.firmfriends.us/GeeksHomePages/subj-video-and-audio.html#implementing-video-thumbnails

My prototype example is here:  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/

Also, I couldn't solve how to bind to the existing seek-bar in video-js,
so I added my own dedicated slider to view the thumbnails.  That
decision was mostly based on the need to use 'hover'/'onMouseOver' if
one wants to use video-js's seekbar, and those gestures don't translate
well to touch-screens (mobile devices).

Cheers.  Hope this helps.

EDIT: I've upgraded my earlier implementation (where I had added my own dedicated slider because I didn't understand how to get the behaviors from VideoJS's built-in seekbar.)

I now have it working, using the builtin seekbar.
The prototype implementation is (still) here:
  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/